# Literals wrapping in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sorry .

I don't know why it is not working.

if i am writing

```html
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date()">click</button>
```

above one is not working .

If i am writing

```html
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">click</button>
```

this one is working .

the only difference i got the literals only  "" ,''

But why this is occurring ?

why i have to choose the alternate literals only ,not the same?

Thank you

Comment: Just look at how the HTML is colored, and it should be obvious. You are setting `onclick` to `document.getElementById(`, because that's where the text literal ends. If you want to avoid this, don't use inline code.

Comment: The `""` is part of the onClick() method so your browser will break your code if will encounter the `"` in between, making it unusable, that's why you need to use `'` .

Comment: This is one of the many reasons why inline JS is not a good idea...

Comment: yes i am not in favour of inline code.
this question always arises to my mind.
so i feel free to ask here.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need the complete expression

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date()
```

inside your onclick. If you start the onclick-expression with a double quote, the parser only knows, that another " will close the expression. That's why you have to use the different (in this case single) quote.

Same thing, when you start with a single quote:

```
onclick='document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()' // wouldn't work
onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date()' // would work
```